# Is it possible to create an "infinite" stream from a database table using Akka Stream

Tags: slick-3.0, akka-stream

I'm playing with Akka Streams 2.4.2 and am wondering if it's possible to setup a stream which uses a database table for a source and whenever there is a record added to the table that record is materialized and pushed downstream?

### UPDATE: 2/23/16

I've implemented the solution from @PH88. Here's my table definition:

```
case class Record(id: Int, value: String)

class Records(tag: Tag) extends Table[Record](tag, "my_stream") {
  def id = column[Int]("id")
  def value = column[String]("value")
  def * = (id, value) <> (Record.tupled, Record.unapply)
}
```

Here's the implementation:

```
 implicit val system = ActorSystem("Publisher")
 implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
 val db = Database.forConfig("pg-postgres")

 try{
  val newRecStream = Source.unfold((0, List[Record]())) { n =>
    try {
      val q = for (r <- TableQuery[Records].filter(row => row.id > n._1)) yield (r)
      val r = Source.fromPublisher(db.stream(q.result)).collect {
        case rec => println(s"${rec.id}, ${rec.value}"); rec
      }.runFold((n._1, List[Record]())) {
        case ((id, xs), current) => (current.id, current :: xs)
      }

      val answer: (Int, List[Record]) = Await.result(r, 5.seconds)
      Option(answer, None)
    }
    catch { case e:Exception => println(e); Option(n, e) }
  }


   Await.ready(newRecStream.throttle(1, 1.second, 1, ThrottleMode.shaping).runForeach(_ => ()), Duration.Inf)
 }
 finally {
   system.shutdown
   db.close
 }
```

But my problem is that when I attempt to call `flatMapConcat` the type I get is `Serializable`.

### UPDATE: 2/24/16

Updated to try `db.run` suggestion from @PH88:

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem("Publisher")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
val db = Database.forConfig("pg-postgres")
val disableAutoCommit = SimpleDBIO(_.connection.setAutoCommit(false))
val queryLimit = 1

try {
 val newRecStream = Source.unfoldAsync(0) { n =>
     val q = TableQuery[Records].filter(row => row.id > n).take(queryLimit)
     db.run(q.result).map { recs =>
       Some(recs.last.id, recs)
     }
   }
   .throttle(1, 1.second, 1, ThrottleMode.shaping)
   .flatMapConcat { recs =>
      Source.fromIterator(() => recs.iterator)
   }
   .runForeach { rec =>
       println(s"${rec.id}, ${rec.value}")
   }

   Await.ready(newRecStream, Duration.Inf)
 }
 catch
 {
   case ex: Throwable => println(ex)
 }
 finally {
   system.shutdown
   db.close
 }
```

Which works (I changed query limit to 1 since I only have a couple items in my database table currently) - except once it prints the last row in the table the program exists. Here's my log output:

```
17:09:27,982 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
17:09:27,982 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
17:09:27,982 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/Users/xxxxxxx/dev/src/scratch/scala/fpp-in-scala/target/scala-2.11/classes/logback.xml]
17:09:28,062 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
17:09:28,064 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
17:09:28,079 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
17:09:28,102 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [application] to DEBUG
17:09:28,103 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
17:09:28,103 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
17:09:28,103 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
17:09:28,104 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@4278284b - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
17:09:28.117 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - pg-postgres - is starting.
1, WASSSAAAAAAAP!
2, WHAAAAT?!?
3, booyah!
4, what!
5, This rocks!
6, Again!
7, Again!2
8, I love this!
9, Akka Streams rock
10, Tuning jdbc
17:09:39.000 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - pg-postgres - is closing down.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Found the missing piece - need to replace this:

```
Some(recs.last.id, recs)
```

with this:

```
 val lastId = if(recs.isEmpty) n else recs.last.id
 Some(lastId, recs)
```

The call to recs.last.id was throwing `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.last` when the result set was empty.

Comment: The closest I could find is http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.1/dbio.html#streaming .  But this appears to be streaming the results from a static ResultSet which wouldn't provide real time updates...

Comment: @Mark, you could simplify your code by using db.run.  See my updated answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general SQL database is a 'passive' construct and does not actively push changes like what you described.  You can only 'simulate' the 'push' with periodic polling like:

```
val newRecStream = Source

  // Query for table changes
  .unfold(initState) { lastState =>
    // query for new data since lastState and save the current state into newState...
    Some((newState, newRecords))
  }

  // Throttle to limit the poll frequency
  .throttle(...)  

  // breaks down into individual records...
  .flatMapConcat { newRecords =>
    Source.unfold(newRecords) { pendingRecords =>
      if (records is empty) {
        None
      } else {
        // take one record from pendingRecords and save to newRec.  Save the rest into remainingRecords.
        Some(remainingRecords, newRec)
      }
    }
  }
```

**Updated: 2/24/2016**

Pseudo code example based on the 2/23/2016 updates of the question:

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem("Publisher")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
val db = Database.forConfig("pg-postgres")
val queryLimit = 10
try {
  val completion = Source
    .unfoldAsync(0) { lastRowId =>
      val q = TableQuery[Records].filter(row => row.id > lastRowId).take(queryLimit)
      db.run(q.result).map { recs =>
        Some(recs.last.id, recs)
      }
    }
    .throttle(1, 1.second, 1, ThrottleMode.shaping)
    .flatMapConcat { recs =>
      Source.fromIterator(() => recs.iterator)
    }
    .runForeach { rec =>
      println(s"${rec.id}, ${rec.value}")
    }

  // Block forever
  Await.ready(completion, Duration.Inf)

} catch {
  case ex: Throwable => println(ex)
} finally {
  system.shutdown
  db.close
}
```

It will repeatedly execute the query in `unfoldAsync` against the DB, retrieving at most 10 (`queryLimit`) records a time and send the records downstream (-> `throttle` -> `flatMapConcat` -> `runForeach`). The `Await` at the end will actually block forever.

**Updated: 2/25/2016**

Executable 'proof-of-concept' code:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.{ThrottleMode, ActorMaterializer}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Source
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object Infinite extends App{
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("Publisher")
  implicit val ec = system.dispatcher
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  case class Record(id: Int, value: String)
  try {
    val completion = Source
      .unfoldAsync(0) { lastRowId =>
        Future {
          val recs = (lastRowId to lastRowId + 10).map(i => Record(i, s"rec#$i"))
          Some(recs.last.id, recs)
        }
      }
      .throttle(1, 1.second, 1, ThrottleMode.Shaping)
      .flatMapConcat { recs =>
        Source.fromIterator(() => recs.iterator)
      }
      .runForeach { rec =>
        println(rec)
      }

    Await.ready(completion, Duration.Inf)

  } catch {
    case ex: Throwable => println(ex)
  } finally {
    system.shutdown
  }
}
```

Comment: Trying to follow your pseudo code, but I'm still really new. I get stuck when I call `concatFlatMap` because the argument passed in is of type `Serializeable`. Is this because I'm calling `Await`? What should I do instead?

Comment: Figured it out...added `Await.ready(newRecStream.throttle(...`. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I like the simplified syntax, but the query is no longer infinite - it exits at the end of the stream. I want it to continue listening forever, as soon as there's a new record it should pick it up and push it out.

Comment: Mark, no this is infinite.  It will repeatedly execute the query in `unfoldAsync` against the DB,  retrieving at most 10 (`queryLimit`) records a time and send the records downstream (-> throttle -> flatMapConcat -> runForeach).  The last `Await...` will actually block forever.

Comment: I just add yet another piece of code (real executable code :-) ) to illustrate the concept.  You can try run and see.

Comment: Yes, your most recent update 2/25/2016 does run infinitely. However, if you change the implementation to use a database query the process will exit the first time the query returns an empty result. I'm guessing something in the database impl triggers a `Done` result and it shuts down the stream. I'm still digging into why.

Comment: Turns out `recs.last.id` was throwing `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.last` so it was terminating. Once I added a check for `isEmpty` that fixed it. I've updated the OP to demonstrate the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Here is database infinite streaming working code. This has been tested with millions of records being inserted into postgresql database while streaming app is running -

```
package infinite.streams.db

import akka.NotUsed
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.alpakka.slick.scaladsl.SlickSession
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, Sink, Source}
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, ThrottleMode}
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import slick.basic.DatabaseConfig
import slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.{Await, ExecutionContextExecutor}

case class Record(id: Int, value: String) {
  val content = s"<ROW><ID>$id</ID><VALUE>$value</VALUE></ROW>"
}

object InfiniteStreamingApp extends App {

  println("Starting app...")

  implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("Publisher")
  implicit val ec: ExecutionContextExecutor = system.dispatcher
  implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

  println("Initializing database configuration...")
  val databaseConfig: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] = DatabaseConfig.forConfig[JdbcProfile]("postgres3")
  implicit val session: SlickSession = SlickSession.forConfig(databaseConfig)

  import databaseConfig.profile.api._

  class Records(tag: Tag) extends Table[Record](tag, "test2") {
    def id = column[Int]("c1")

    def value = column[String]("c2")

    def * = (id, value) <> (Record.tupled, Record.unapply)
  }

  val db = databaseConfig.db

  println("Prime for streaming...")

  val logic: Flow[(Int, String), (Int, String), NotUsed] = Flow[(Int, String)].map {
    case (id, value) => (id, value.toUpperCase)
  }

  val fetchSize = 5
  try {
    val done = Source
      .unfoldAsync(0) {
      lastId =>
        println(s"Fetching next: $fetchSize records with id > $lastId")
        val query = TableQuery[Records].filter(_.id > lastId).take(fetchSize)
        db.run(query.result.withPinnedSession)
          .map {
            recs => Some(recs.last.id, recs)
          }
    }
      .throttle(5, 1.second, 1, ThrottleMode.shaping)
      .flatMapConcat {
        recs => Source.fromIterator(() => recs.iterator)
      }
      .map(x => (x.id, x.content))
      .via(logic)
      .log("*******Post Transformation******")
//      .runWith(Sink.foreach(r => println("SINK: " + r._2)))
// Use runForeach or runWith(Sink)
      .runForeach(rec => println("REC: " + rec))

    println("Waiting for result....")
    Await.ready(done, Duration.Inf)

  } catch {
    case ex: Throwable => println(ex.getMessage)
  } finally {
    println("Streaming end successfully")
    db.close()
    system.terminate()
  }

}



application.conf

akka {
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  loglevel = "INFO"
}
# Load using SlickSession.forConfig("slick-postgres")
postgres3 {
  profile = "slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$"
  db {
    dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DriverDataSource"
    properties = {
      driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
      url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/testdb"
      user = "postgres"
      password = "postgres"
    }
    numThreads = 2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one possibility is you can setup a source unfold to setup an infinite stream.

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source/unfold.html

with that you could setup a source like so:
val beginoffset = 0L
val fetchSize = 10000

```
(Source.unfold(initialOffset) { current =>
   fetchOnlyMethod(offset) match {
     case values if values.isEmpty => Some(offset, values)
     case values => Some((offset++fetchSize), values)
   }
 })
```

then use the 'fetchOnly' method to get a chunk of data from the offset to the fetch limit.

if you want the source to stop when it reaches the end of the table, you can replace the 'values.isEmpty' clause with:

```
case values if values.isEmpty => None
```

the unfold logic will keep running until it reaches a None. In terms of the tuple it uses, the first value is what is iterated on in the fold logic and the second value is what is passed down in the stream with every loop.